# Converting for loop output from list to dataframe in R

Tags: r

Going to ask this via a simplified code (logic is kinda wonky - but it's similar to my situation), the current code I'm working with is long and might be too many words without value. I will happily add what's needed to answer this:

I have a situation with a for loop such as:

```
data2 <- data.frame("Chocolate" = c(0.25), "Strawberry" = c(.16),
                "Vanilla" = c(0.64), "Blueberry" = c(.75))

for (i in 1:4) { 
    freqSim <- data.frame(sample(0:1, length(1:100), replace=T, prob = c(1-data2[i],data2[i])))  

    lossCol <- freqSim*(runif(n=100, min=0, max=7000))

    costAvg <- mean(as.numeric(unlist(lossCol)))
    costSD <- sd(as.numeric(unlist(lossCol)))

    costAvg <- formatC(costAvg, format='d', big.mark=",")
    costSD <- formatC(costSD, format='d', big.mark= ",")

    stats <- list()
    stats[[i]] <- list(costAvg,costSD)

    print(stats[[i]])
}
```

where I get returned a vector such as:

```
[[1]] 
[1] "1,261" 

[[2]] 
[1] "2,103"

[[1]] 
[1] "313"

[[2]] 
[1] "1,165"

[[1]] 
[1] "2,073"

[[2]] 
[1] "2,206"

[[1]] 
[1] "2,417"

[[2]] 
[1] "2,258"
```

I would ideally like a matrix that looks like:

```
          Chocolate    Strawberry   Vanilla   Blueberry
Label A     1,261       313          2,073      2,417  
Label B     2,103       1,165        2,206      2,258
```

Any way to do this without throwing myself off a cliff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple fix:

```
data2 <- data.frame("Chocolate" = c(0.25), "Strawberry" = c(.16),
      "Vanilla" = c(0.64), "Blueberry" = c(.75))

stats <- data.frame( row.names = c("Label A", "Label B") )

for (i in 1:4) { 
    freqSim <- data.frame(sample(0:1, length(1:100), replace=T, 
            prob = c(1-data2[i],data2[i])))  

    lossCol <- freqSim*(runif(n=100, min=0, max=7000))

    costAvg <- mean(as.numeric(unlist(lossCol)))
    costSD <- sd(as.numeric(unlist(lossCol)))

    costAvg <- formatC(costAvg, format='d', big.mark=",")
    costSD <- formatC(costSD, format='d', big.mark= ",")

    stats["Label A", i] <- costAvg
    stats["Label B", i] <- costSD
}

colnames(stats) <- colnames(data2)
```

Results:

```
        Chocolate Strawberry Vanilla Blueberry
Label A       764        470   2,003     2,932
Label B     1,674      1,418   2,202     2,315
```

I would encourage you to look at using `tidyr` for these kinds of manipulations instead of doing it in base R, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by using `simplify2array`

```
res <- simplify2array(stats)
dimnames(res) <- list(paste("Label", c("A", "B")), names(data2))
```

NOTE: Make sure to define the

```
stats <- list()
```

outside the `for` loop

A better option is to  assign have the `length` pre-allocated i.e.

```
stats <- vector("list", length(data2))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly what you gave as the output table, try this. Didnt have time to apply the right naming conventions. Please excuse.

```
data2 <- data.frame("Chocolate" = c(0.25), "Strawberry" = c(.16),
                    "Vanilla" = c(0.64), "Blueberry" = c(.75))
x = c("Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla", "Blueberry")
y = c("Label A", "Label B")

data3 = matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
colnames(data3) = x
row.names(data3) = y

for (i in 1:4) { 
  freqSim <- data.frame(sample(0:1, length(1:100), replace = T, prob = c(1-data2[i],data2[i])))  

  lossCol <- freqSim*(runif(n=100, min=0, max=7000))

  costAvg <- mean(as.numeric(unlist(lossCol)))
  costSD <- sd(as.numeric(unlist(lossCol)))

  costAvg <- formatC(costAvg, format='d', big.mark=",")
  costSD <- formatC(costSD, format='d', big.mark= ",")

  data3[1, i] = costAvg
  data3[2, i] = costSD
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with `dplyr`. It won't give you the matrix you wanted, but it's a neater way to avoid the for-loop:

```
freqSim <- lapply(names(data2), function(x)
                  sample(0:1, length(1:100), replace=T, 
                  prob=c(1-data2[x], data2[x])))
names(freqSim) <- names(data2)

lossCol <- lapply(freqSim, function(x) x*(runif(n=100, min=0, max=7000))) 

do.call(data.frame, lossCol) %>% 
    gather(type, val) %>% 
    group_by(type) %>% 
    summarise(mean=mean(val), sd=sd(val)) %>% 
    mutate_at(.cols=vars(mean, sd), .funs = funs(format(., format="d", big.mark=","))) 

# A tibble: 4 × 3
        type       mean        sd
       <chr>      <chr>     <chr>
1  Blueberry 2,911.8587 2,481.310
2  Chocolate   810.6141 1,820.357
3 Strawberry   680.2027 1,659.491
4    Vanilla 2,302.0011 2,305.148
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a matrix format output, you can do this in base R using `outer`. For example, to calculate a mean and median on each column of `mtcars`, you could do:

```
> outer(list(mean=mean, median=median), as.data.frame(mtcars), Vectorize(function(f,y) f(y)))
             mpg    cyl       disp       hp      drat      wt     qsec     vs      am   gear   carb
mean   20.090625 6.1875 230.721875 146.6875 3.5965625 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625 3.6875 2.8125
median 19.200000 6.0000 196.300000 123.0000 3.6950000 3.32500 17.71000 0.0000 0.00000 4.0000 2.0000
```

The first argument of outer is a named list of functions you want to apply, the second is the columns to iterate over, and the final argument is a function to evaluate a function on a column. `Vectorize` is needed here.

In your case, I would split up your code into three parts:

Generate the samples:

```
>     freqSim <- lapply(data2, function(x) sample(0:1, length(1:100), replace=T, prob=c(1-x,x)) *(runif(n=100, min=0, max=7000)))
```

Which look like this:

```
> str(freqSim)
List of 4
 $ Chocolate : num [1:100] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Strawberry: num [1:100] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Vanilla   : num [1:100] 4175 1456 0 1201 852 ...
 $ Blueberry : num [1:100] 0 3896 3794 5096 2901 ...
```

Declare your functions:

```
> funs <- list(`Label A`=function(x) formatC(mean(x), format='d', big.mark=","), 
               `Label B`=function(x) formatC(sd(x), format='d', big.mark=",") )
```

Use `outer`:

```
> outer(funs, freqSim, Vectorize(function(f,y) f(y)))
        Chocolate Strawberry Vanilla Blueberry
Label A "518"     "427"      "2,044" "2,441"  
Label B "1,417"   "1,290"    "2,250" "2,259"
```